# How to create/mock a class thats already mocked in Mockito unit tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I have a class FileService that needs some unit tests to be run.

```
Class FileService {
    @Autowired
    ServiceClass serviceClass;

    method_class_FileService() {
         serviceClass.method_service_class();
    }
}

Class ServiceClass {
     @Autowired
     UtilsClass utilsClass;

     method_service_class() {
           utilsClass.method();
     }
}

Class UtilsClass {
     method() {
     // Some implementation
     }
}
```

Mockito test case

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FileServiceImplTest {
     @InjectMocks
     FileService fileService;
     
     @Mock
     ServiceClass serviceClass;

     @Mock
     UtilsClass utilsClass;
     
     @Test
     public void testMethod_class_FileService() {
          when(serviceClass.method_service_class()).thenCallRealMethod();
          when(utilsClass.method_service_class()).thenCallRealMethod();
          fileService.method_class_FileService();
          //Assertions
     }
}
```

When the `fileService.method_class_FileService()` is called, it throws NullPointerException while calling the `utilsClass.method_service_class()`

Tried to mock the objects which did not work.
Tried to use thenCallRealMethod which also did not work.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Names should be camelCase not snake_case.

Comment: The method in utilsclass should not be called at all, because the class which are calling it should be a mock.

Comment: Noted the point on java naming conventions. And on the mock, I was using `thenCallRealMethod` since the serviceClass was straight forward conversions only.

Comment: I think you have to `spy` `serviceClass` if you want to inject mocks

Comment: can you add access modifiers please to each variable

Answer (score 0):

Replace @InjectMocks to @Mock in case you call the service directly from your testcase as @InjectMocks mock the whole class with null values

Comment: You should give definition between annotations and related dependencies used.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and reading through some documents I understood that its possible to mock only the immediate class calls while doing the mocks unit tests.

Also the right way was to test only the `FileService` by mocking the `ServiceClass` using `when(..).thenReturn(..);` and testing the other methods in the `ServiceClass` and the `UtilsClass` by creating separate test classes like `ServiceClassTest` & `UtilsClassTest` and individually unit test by asserting only the values/conversions that were implemented in the block.